# Bash command using xargs and xargs -0

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I just found difference between two commands:

```
echo sum.txt| xargs cat
```

This will output content of sum.txt

```
echo sum.txt| xargs -0 cat
```

This shows error:

```
cat: sum.txt
: No such file or directory
```

I  know -0 will treat null bytes as delimiter. And i think the new line starts with : is because echo command produce new lines. And doesn't produce output like:

```
cat: sum.txt: No such file or directory
```

But if echo produce new lines why the first command can succeed? since xargs use white spaces as delimiter by default.

Comment: Newline is whitespace. (Also tab, formfeed, and of course space)

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening will become more clear if you replace `cat` with `echo -n` as an experiment.

```
echo sum.txt| xargs  echo -n
echo sum.txt | xargs -0 echo -n
```

In the first example, `xargs` breaks on the newline and *discards the newline*, leaving just `sum.txt`.

In the second example, `xargs` breaks on the end of the EOF at the end of the output of the first `echo`, resulting in the string `'sum.txt\n'`.